# Column-wide (as opposed to link-wide) on hover effect

Tags: css

I'm editing my question, as I feel it is not very clear, and putting the answer both in the question and here:

we aim to represent a file explorer as a column of links consisting of:

(Optionally) a little "+" or "-" image (for expanding or retracting folders).

A file name. Hovering over a file name should change the background of the file name up to the right edge *of the column*, even if the file name is short.

Solution found:

```
<div style="display:block;">
  <img src="+.png" />
  <a style="display:inline-block;width:200px;">A file name</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This makes no sense to me. An image would be far better.

Comment: the lines represent the on hover background I would like to change

Comment: You have a concept in mind but this drawing doesn't explain it to me... all the links look exactly the same. A simple graphic would suffice.

Comment: I would simply like the background of my links to change on hover, and that whatever the width of the link, the same width of background would change, for a nicer visual effect. Bad luck with display:block; it also changes the background of the image link on the left, which is undesirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm editing my question, as I feel it is not very clear, and putting the answer both in the question and here:

we aim to represent a file explorer as a column of links consisting of:

(Optionally) a little "+" or "-" image (for expanding or retracting folders).

A file name. Hovering over a file name should change the background of the file name up to the right edge *of the column*, even if the file name is short.

Solution found:

```
<div style="display:block;">
  <img src="+.png" />
  <a style="display:inline-block;width:200px;">A file name</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 <a><img src="imagePlus.png" /></a><a class="forHover">Linklinklink2</a>
```

Css

```
 .forHover
 {
     display:block;
 }
```

Comment: Nope, this is what I did, and the first link (the + image)'s background also changes.